# What are the differences in architecture of Model 2 and Model 3B+? (SD card not working in model 3B+)

Tags: pi-2, sd-card, pi-3b+

I have two raspberries (model 2 and model 3B+) and two sd cards. I wanted to swap the cards.

The **card from model 2 is not recognised in model 3B+**.

There is no green LED which indicates that the Pi cannot read from the sd card.

The other way around is working fine showing that it is not a problem of the cards or of the card slot.

Is there any big difference in [architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi) between the two models? I would imagine 32/64-bit but should a 32bit OS not also boot in model 3B+?

---

I bought the Model 2 in October 2015 and installed Noobs Jessy. I updated to stretch in 2019. It is a Model **2B**.

SD cards are both from sandisk, 64GB and 8GB. The 8GB is working in both devices.

---

Everything is up-to-date:

```
13:07:22 [root@raspberrypi ~]# rpi-update
 *** Raspberry Pi firmware updater by Hexxeh, enhanced by AndrewS and Dom
 *** Performing self-update
 *** Relaunching after update
 *** Raspberry Pi firmware updater by Hexxeh, enhanced by AndrewS and Dom
 *** Your firmware is already up to date
13:07:27 [root@raspberrypi ~]# apt update && apt upgrade
OK:1 http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease
OK:2 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian stretch InRelease
OK:3 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch InRelease
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
Alle Pakete sind aktuell.
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
Paketaktualisierung (Upgrade) wird berechnet... Fertig
0 aktualisiert, 0 neu installiert, 0 zu entfernen und 0 nicht aktualisiert.
```

---

I wonder why there is not even a single read (green light). Maybe it has something to do with the partition table.

Originally, my system was set up on the 8GB card. I then cloned this partition scheme to the 64GB card and enlarged the main partition to fully use the 64GB. I therefore had to move the partition which lays behind the main partion. This worked well with the 64GB card in my Model 2. Maybe Model 3 has a problem with it.

Answer (score 3):

You need an OS image that came out after the release of the product, or you can upgrade the SD card in your Pi 2 and that should do the trick, provided the OS version (e.g. Stretch) came out since the 3B+. Raspbian Buster came out recently so you probably just want to use that, knowing that it supports all models.

The answer to the question "What are the differences in architecture of Model 2 and Model 3B+?" is "it depends". The original Pi 2 had the BCM2836 SoC, but after the Pi 3 came out (with the BCM2837 SoC), they started making Pi 2s with the 2837 chip. You can see this number written on the chip itself.

Comment: I cannot read the chip because I clued a cooler on it. My OS was Jessy (probably before 3B+) until I updated to Stretch recently.

Comment: Also, I would suspect that there should be at least one read from the sd card even if firmware is not working.

Answer (score 2):

The most likely explanation is the boot files need updating.

You should be able to this on the Pi2 by doing a (sudo) apt update and apt upgrade.

If that doesn't work you might have to do a `sudo rpi-update` with the SD card in the Pi2.

Comment: I did both successfully, but still no read from sd card, while the other card works fine. On the other card there is a recently installed OpenELEC, btw.

Comment: I'm afraid that exhausts my knowledge.  Perhaps work through the raspberrypi.org/forums boot sticky?